# Fill Rectangles based on Starting Point but must be in a line

Tags: c#, drawing, rectangles

I know someone can help me.

I'm busy developing a select the word game but I'm not sure how to highlight the selected letters.

I'm currently creating a grid of blocks.

Then when the user clicks and moves the mouse from on block to another I use the Rect to check if they intersect when they do I mark that block as selected but I need to ignore the block number 2 when block number 3 is selected same thing should happen when block number 4 is selected. So that pattern is: 1,3,5,7 blocks number 2,4,6 should not be selected.

[image]

Kind regards,

Johan

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it to be a standard word-guessing game where word letters always fall in the boxes which are on a standing-line, sleeping-line or line at angle of 45 degrees. In which case you just need a start box and end box of user's input and you can select/mark all the boxes from starting box by adding +1 till you reach last box.

Say user stared at startBox(rowStart,colStart) till lastBox(rowLast,colLast) 
So all you need to do is

```
rowPos = startBox.rowStart;
colPos = startBox.colStart;

do{
  mark startBox(rowPos, colPos)
  rowPos++;
  colPos++;
} while(rowPos<=rowLast && colPos<=colLast)
```

Note: You will have to evaluate startBox and lastBox to figure out whether user is going bottom-right, bottom-left, top-right or top-left and accordingly add/subtract 1 to row and/or column.